# Как правильно привязать поля класса к UserControl

Tags: wpf, binding, usercontrol, catel

Есть UserControl, на нем содержатся несколько текстбоксов для изменения полей класса. Так вот никак не получается забиндить эти поля класса в двухстороннем режиме на текстбоксы UserControl.

View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Editor3.Modules.Views.CreateView"
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Editor3.Modules.ViewModels">
<Grid>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Description}" />
            <Button Content="Create" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.CreateCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace Editor3.Modules.ViewModels

{
    public class CreateViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public CreateViewModel()
        {
            CreateCommand = new Command(Create);
        }

        public Command CreateCommand { get; private set; }

        World World
        {
            get { return GetValue<World>(WorldProperty); }
            set { SetValue(WorldProperty, value);}
        }

        public static readonly PropertyData WorldProperty = RegisterProperty("World", typeof(World));
    }
}
```

Model:

```
namespace Library.Objects
{
    using Catel.Data;
    using Catel.MVVM;

    public class World : ModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        [Model]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return GetValue<string>(NameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly PropertyData NameProperty = RegisterProperty("Name", typeof(string), "Name");
        [Model]
        public string Description
        {
            get { return GetValue<string>(DescriptionProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DescriptionProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly PropertyData DescriptionProperty = RegisterProperty("Description", typeof(string), "Description");
    }
}
```

Так вот нажатие кнопки вызывает правильную функцию, т.е. биндится нормально а поля никак не хотят!

Comment: А зачем в вас такой сложный Binding для Button'а?

Comment: единственный вариант который заработал. перелопатил уже кучу вариантов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно используете Catel framework. Атрибут [Model] используется для свойств у ViewModel. У ViewModel должны быть свойства Name и Description. Перечитайте документацию еще раз.

```
namespace Editor3.Modules.ViewModels
{

public class CreateViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public CreateViewModel(World World)
    {
        this.World = World;
        CreateCommand = new Command(Create);
    }

    public Command CreateCommand { get; private set; }

    [Model]
    World World
    {
        get { return GetValue<World>(WorldProperty); }
        set { SetValue(WorldProperty, value);}
    }

    [ViewModelToModel("World")]
    public string Description
    {
           get { return GetValue<string>(DescriptionProperty); }
           set { SetValue(DescriptionProperty, value); }
    }

    [ViewModelToModel("World")]
    public string Name
    {
           get { return GetValue<string>(NameProperty); }
           set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly PropertyData WorldProperty = RegisterProperty("World", typeof(World));

    public static readonly PropertyData DescriptionProperty = RegisterProperty("Description", typeof(string), null);

    public static readonly PropertyData NameProperty = RegisterProperty("Name", typeof(string), null);
}
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! 6 часов убил на поиск ответа а оказалось копал совсем не в ту сторону! В моем случае все заработало. Насчет документации по катель обязательно почитаю еще раз, чтобы не убивать столько времени на не то!